# Defining a set of intervals such that $f(x)$ is larger than a given value

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Consider a continuous function $f(x)$ defined on the interval $[0,\,1]$. My question: How do you define the set of intervals such that $f(x)>V$, where $V$ is a constant? You may assume that all of the intervals can be calculated numerically and that there are finitely many.

My attempt was as follows
\begin{equation}
X := \big\{ x \,\, | \,\, f(x) >V\big\} = \big\{ (x_0,\,x_1),\,\dots, \, (x_{i},\,x_{i+1}), \, \cdots ,\, (x_{N-1},\,x_{N})\big\} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $x_i<x_{i+1}$ for $i=0,\,\dots,\,i,\,\dots,\,N.$

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Finding the roots to $f(x)=V$ can be quite complicated, depending on the nature of $f(x)$.  Is that really what you are asking about?  Or are you just asking about notation?

Comment: Your notation is wrong. $\{x \mid f(x)>V\}$ is a set of NUMBERS, a subset of $[0,1]$, while $\big\{ (x_0,\,x_1),\,\dots, \, (x_{i},\,x_{i+1}), \, \cdots ,\, (x_{N-1},\,x_{N})\big\}$ is a set of SETS, since its elements are intervals. Which one is the one you are trying to define?

Comment: If notation is your goal, then note that there is no reason to imagine that there are only finitely many intervals.  Suppose $f(x)$ is $0$ for $x=0$ or $x=\frac 1n$  for every $n\in \mathbb N$, and positive otherwise.

Comment: Also, the numbers of intervals where a function is greater than $V$ is not necessarily finite.

Comment: Can you edit your post for clarity?  As it stands it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @lulu I'm asking about the notation. You can assume that you can actually find these intervals.

Comment: @jjagmath I'm trying to define the second one.

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect that, as I say, it's not at all clear.

Comment: @lulu you can assume that there finite intervals.

Comment: In any case, your notation is inadequate.  There might be infinitely many such intervals and they need not all be open.  Why not just stick with $\{x\in [0,1]\,|\,f(x)>V\}$.

Comment: @Giraffes4thewin Then you should fix your question, because it says that $f$ is an arbitrary continuous function.

Comment: It's not reasonable to expect your readers to guess your intentions, nor to expect them to guess which unstated assumptions they are intended to make.

Comment: Sorry, It's been edited.

Comment: In any case, your notation is still inadequate as it fails to take into account that the first and last intervals might be closed on one side, and that it is possible that $x_{2i-1} = x_{2i}$ for some (or all)  of the $i$.

Comment: And you're still stating the equality between a set of numbers and a set of intervals.

Comment: That was my attempt, if its wrong then fine. Thanks @lulu for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining $X =\{x \in [0,1]: f(x)>V\}$, which is exactly the $f$-preimage of the interval $(V, \infty)$. You've said $f$ is continuous, so as the preimage of an open set, $X$ is open. Open sets are the union of disjoint open intervals, where since we're working in $[0,1]$ we consider $[0,a)$ and $(a,1]$ to be open sets since we're working in a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ If all you need is a way to justify that this set of intervals exists, then you're done.

If you actually want to compute the intervals then we can potentially leverage continuity. Say you can find the set $A = \{x \in [0,1]: f(x)=V\}$. You can then partition $[0,1]$ into intervals or points that are equal to $V$, and intervals that are either strictly greater or strictly less. For each unknown interval, just pick an interior point to determine whether $f>V$ or $f<V$ on that interval; you're guaranteed one or the other by continuity.

Comment: The OP has $f$ defined on $[0,1]$, not $\Bbb R$, so $X$ is open IN $[0,1]$, and then the intervals are not necessarily open.

Comment: Right I missed that. They're still open in $[0,1]$ with the subspace topology, which is to say that $[0,a)$ and $(a,1]$ are "honorary" open intervals.